# How come I can't access the methods of my subview?

Tags: ios, swift

In my ViewDidLoad:

```
    let spiralDimension = CGFloat(ScreenWidth! * 0.10)
    let spiralName = "spiral.png"
    let spiralImage = UIImage(named: spiralName)

    spiralView = UIImageView(image: spiralImage!)
    spiralView!.frame = CGRect(x: ScreenWidth! / 2 - spiralDimension/2, y: (ScreenHeight!-TabBarHeight!) / 2 - spiralDimension/2 , width: spiralDimension, height: spiralDimension)
    spiralView!.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(spiralView!) //works!!!
```

Somewhere later...

```
func fadeBackground(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.fadeTime, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {
        var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme.count)))

        var subviews = self.view.subviews
        for v in subviews{
            if v.isKindOfClass(UIImageView){
                println(v) //correctly prints my spiral!
                v.tintColor = CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme[randomIndex] //can't do it. XCode won't even auto-complete
            }
        }
    }) { (stuff Bool) -> Void in

    }
}
```

I can't `assign tintColor to v`, even though it prints my class correctly. Can't build successfully.

Answer (score 2):

`subviews` returns an array of `AnyObject`. Thus, you need to cast `v` in order to set `tintColor`.

Try:

```
for v in subviews{
   if let v = v as? UIImageView {
      println(v)
      v.tintColor = CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme[randomIndex]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to typecast it.

```
if v.isKindOfClass(UIImageView){
  let iv = v as! UIImageView
  v.tintColor = ...
```

The problem is that the `subviews` property is defined in iOS as a variable of type `[AnyObject]` so Swift doesn't know that your subviews are members of `UIView`, which has the property `tintColor`.